# Is there a way to search radius by radius in Google maps api v3?

Tags: search, google-maps-api-3, kml

So what I am aiming to do is to have radiuses saved in the database. I'm not sure if I need to use kml for this. Then I want the website users to be able to search by place and also give a radius to the search. The corresponding database entries should show up of course. This means the search will be a place with a radius which must search on the database of saved radiuses as well. Is this possible? How is best to save the areas? And how can I perform a search like this using the Google maps api? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps API v3 doesn't provide such function per-se, but it does provide wrappers to APIs that do offer radius based search like

- Your own records, stored in a fusiontable. See [FusionTableQuery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#FusionTablesQuery)
- Google Places, see [PlaceSearchRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlaceSearchRequest)
- Google Maps Engine (I'm not sure you can filter by radius on the client side tho) see [MapsEngineLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapsEngineLayer)

Now, since you're already planning to save your data to a database, you don't really need to rely on Google Maps API embedded functions. You can query the database yourself and deal with the results later in the form of markers, for example

Any geo enabled database will allow you to search for radius, specifying the center, radius and optionally sorting by distance. If you wanted to search, say, all the records within a 1000m distance from {lng: 30, lat:70}, iIn MongoDB it would be something like

```
db.Yourpoints.find({
  "location":{
    $near:{
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
         -70,
         30
      ] 
    },
   $maxDistance: 1000 
  }
});
```

Whereas in PostgreSQL (with Postgis) it would be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Yourpoints
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(the_geom, ST_MakePoint(-70,30)) <= 1000
```

**edit** oh, and I don't understand why would you save radiuses in the DB. Do you mean, save predefined queries? persist resultsets?

Comment: No, I didn't mean it like that. My idea is to save ltd and lng in the database and also a from to ltd lng. Although it's going to save a square rather than a circle I know, but it's easier to query. I need to build this system using mysql. I'm going to check the sources you gave me. Thanks. My current plan is to use the geocode api and go through all my database entries and check if the lng and ltd is in the area the search has.

Comment: MySQL does support geo queries too. [ST_Within](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html) is perfect to check if a point is contained on a bounding box.